Bad Request error when trying to connect Drapcode to Supabase
I tried to connect Drapcode to Supabase with the external API feature of Drapcode. I inserted their my project url as well as my public anon key. Furthermore, I told it to send data out of a collection and configured, that the email column of the auth.user table (a table managed by Supabase) should get the value from the username column in the collection and the password column from the password column. As a method I picked POST. I also wrote the content type into the header with the API key.
In the frontend, I created a collection formular, which sends data into that collection, from which it then gets send into the SUpabase auth.users table.
But when I start the preview I get the following error in the console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
drapcode.min.js:1 ==> External API error :>>  Error: Request failed with status code 400
at createError (axios.js:1291:23)
at settle (axios.js:1255:15)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (axios.js:1090:15)

I already tried several things, but nothing seems to work.
Could you please help me with that?
thank you & best wishes
Benni
I tried to use the secret key as the API key, but that didn't worked out.
